# Presenting interstitial ad when switching between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

So I assume this is a fairly common use-case. After a player finishes a game, I want an interstitial ad to be presented. When that ad is dismissed, the player should be back at the menu.

The way I've done it currently is to first send the player back to the menu, and then in viewWillAppear present the interstitial. This does however briefly display the menu before the ad, which isn't terribly pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Present the Ad to the `window.rootViewController` of the AppDelegate `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` before poping back the menu so when the user dismisses the Ad the Menu would be already presented.